# SharePoint Workflow - lookup field

Tags: designer-workflow

I created a list that has two cascading items using lookup fields. I am trying to generate an email using the data that is displayed however i keep receiving an error.

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate your question also mention what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try get information from the original items in other lists with filter depended on lookup field.